# Passing action plus appended string to tag in Play

Tags: tags, playframework

I'm trying to pass an action to a custom tag, but instead of just the bare action, I also want to append a string to the generated url.

With just an action it works:

```
#{nav.menu label: 'Log In', url: @access.AccessControl.login() /}
```

But `#{nav.menu label: 'Log In', url: @access.AccessControl.login() + '?url=' + request.url /}` results in

> MissingMethodException : No signature
>   of method:
>   play.mvc.Router$ActionDefinition.plus()
>   is applicable for argument types:
>   (java.lang.String) values: [?url=]
>   Possible solutions:
>   use([Ljava.lang.Object;),
>   split(groovy.lang.Closure),
>   is(java.lang.Object), wait(), any(),
>   dump().

When I try `#{nav.menu label: 'Log In', url: @{access.AccessControl.login()} + "?url=" + request.url /}`, it says `#{nav.menu} is not closed}`:

So then I tried

```
%{ loginPath = @access.AccessControl.login(); }%
#{nav.menu label: 'Log In', url: loginPath + "?url=" + request.url /}
```

but then it says "The template /app/views/main.html does not compile : unexpected token: @ "

If I do this, the action isn't replaced with a path:

```
%{ loginPath = '@{access.AccessControl.login()}' }%
#{nav.menu label: 'Log In', url: loginPath + "?url=" + request.url /}
```

So I'm pretty much out of ideas.  What does it want from me?

---

I've been able to get it working using the following
 but it seems like there must be a better way:

```
#{nav.menu label: 'Log In', url: play.mvc.Router.reverse('access.AccessControl.login').url + '?url=' + request.url /}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass url parameter with .add(paramName, paramValue)

for example, I'll define my own anchor tag like this

views/tags/anchor.html

```
%{
action = anchor ?: _arg;
%}
#{a action}my own anchor#{/a}
```

and I can use it like:

```
#{anchor @Application.newAction().add('name', 'john').add('nick', 'johnny') /}<br />
```

this would generate the following html

```
<a href="/application/newaction?nick=juancho&amp;name=juan">mi propio anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
%{ url = request.url }%
#{nav.menu label: 'Log In', url: @access.AccessControl.login(url) /}
```

Comment: Then I get "No route able to invoke action access.AccessControl.login was found.". Do I need to do anything special in the routes file to make this work?

Comment: is it declared in the routes file? By default, I fear there is no route targeting your controller (in a package moreover)